# factorable trinomial / polynomial

Tags: java, polynomials, quadratic, jcreator, factoring

so I want to create a program that prints out a factorable quadratic equation when the user enters a value, c, and a = 1,. The program should determine all the possible Integer values of b so that the trinomial prints out in the form x^2 + bx + c

An example would be if the user entered -4 for c the program should print out: 
x^2 - 4 
x^2 - 3x - 4

So far this is what I have done with my code, I am trying to figure out how to execute the program but I really am having trouble of where to go from here. If anyone can offer some help that would be much appreciated!

```
public class FactorableTrinomials
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.println("A trinomial in standard form is ax^2 + bx + 
        c. \nIf a = 1, this program will output all factorable trinomials 
        given the entered c value.");

        System.out.print("\nEnter an integer “c” value: ");
        int numC = scan.nextInt();

        final int NUMA= 1;
        int numB;


        if (numC > 0)
        {
            int factors;

            System.out.print("\nThe factors of " + numC + " are: ");

            for(factors = 1; factors <= numC; factors++)    //determines 
            factors and how many there are
            {
                if(numC % factors == 0)
                {
                    System.out.print(factors + " ");
                }
            }
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "execute the program"? How "execution" of this specific code differs from generic way described in any primer book?

Comment: I just meant to say that I am trying to properly code the program so I can print out the necessary information

Answer (score 0):

First, find the pairs of integer which multiplies to c.
all possible values of b will then be the sum of the pair of integer.

A simple way to find the pairs of integer is to loop 2 variables from -c to c and check if the product is c. eg:

```
for(int i = -1 * numC; i <= numC; i++) {
    for(int j = -1* numC; j<= numC;j++) {
        if(i * j == numC) {
            int b = i + j;

            //print solution, if b == 0 then don't print the second term
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is making much more sense to me now, but the problem arises that this will then print each equation twice. I believe that the problem lies in my initial approach to find the factors.